# SQL Faster Process Time with Insert/Update

Tags: mysql, sql

My system currently receives 1600 records. All the records are parsed to create a query to insert all records into the database as one single query.

I've checked that the parsing takes about 1 second or even less. However, with the query, the process time is about 12 seconds.

Here is a sample of my query:

```
INSERT INTO `SAMPLE` 
(`RECORD_NUMBER`, `ITEM`, `DESCRIPTION`)
VALUES 
('1', 'Sample Item 1', 'test'),
('2', 'Sample Item 2', 'test'),
('3', 'Sample Item 3', 'test') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `ITEM` = (CASE `RECORD_NUMBER` 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Cash'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Credit Card' 
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Debit Card' END),
    `DESCRIPTION` = (CASE `RECORD_NUMBER` 
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Sample Text 1' 
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Sample Text 2'
        WHEN '3' THEN 'Sample Text 3' END);
```

My query is as simple as inserting new records if it does not exist, but if it does exist, it will just update the already existing one.

Times 530 of that query (1600 Records), is almost the same number of records I insert/update.

Is there a way to make the process faster? Hopefully with minimal changes to my query if there are any.

Language: Javascript
; Database: MySQL Workbench

Comment: Please add the output of `show create table sample\G` and `explain <your_insert_query>;`

Comment: @fancyPants - i cannot provide the create table for this one since table is not a real table that I'm using but rather a sample for this question only.

Comment: When you can't provide information, I can't help you. Bye

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mysql developer (SQL Sever), but I might be able to point you in the right direction to get you going.

I've googled a bit now what the mysql equivalents would be, but unable to test, so you might need to spend some more time to research it.

Firstly, I would use the [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) function, to "bulk load" the file, into a [memory table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Once you have it there, you can insert/update with inner and left joins.

Hope this helps!